# Redirect to a AJAX URL

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

Have to redirect to the below URL:

```
AjaxView1?catalogId=12345&storeId=67890&List=123#AjaxView2?ListId=123&storeId=67890&catalogId=12345
```

I am passing this value as hidden prameter in form and redirecting from a java class. Somehow, the AJAX view is not being picked up. It is redirecting to the former `AJAXView1`.

Can you please suggest what I need to change so that it gets redirected to a second AJAX view "`Ajaxiew2`".

I would like to know, how will it handle the # symbol in the URLredirection.

**EDIT**

I have a form from where I am passing the hidden parameter value of URL.

```
<form name ="LogonList" action="someActionCode"  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="storeId" value="67890">
<input type="hidden" name="URL" value="AjaxView1?catalogId=12345&storeId=67890&List=123#AjaxView2?ListId=123&storeId=67890&catalogId=12345 >
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

someActionCode will call a java class which will perform some business logic and after business logic gets executed, it will redirectURL to the URL passed as hidden parameter.

I would like to know, how will it handle the # symbol in the `URLredirection`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing second url as hidden value first do the firstURL work then do any one of the below.

```
response.sendRedirect("/url2");
```

or use this one based on the situation where you want

```
String destination = "url2";
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

or use this one based on the situation where you want

```
String destination = "url2";
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
rd.include(request, response);
```